# Sci-fi short story from the perspective of an unseen narrator talking to a person in a room (the World Trade Center and the letter Q don't exist)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

About 13 years ago I read this short story in a book of sci-fi short stories.  It was told from the perspective of someone who is talking to a person in a room.  The person cannot see the narrator.  The only other details of this story I can recall are:

1. The narrator tells the person that certain things no longer exist such as the World Trade Center (pre 9/11) and the letter Q, and that things seem kind of "kweer".
2. The narrator offers the person a girl, but says that she is not being offered as a "bribe" saying--and I'm paraphrasing--"the powers that be know you well enough not to offer you a piece of ass to get your attention".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

Googling for "world trade center kweer" turned up:

> "Just Another Perfect Day" by John Varley.

[The full text is online](http://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/just-another-perfect-day/) courtesy of *Lightspeed Magazine*, which printed the story in August 2011.  The credit at the bottom says it originally appeared in *Twilight Zone* in 1989.